# Cassandra WriteTimeout when "IS NOT NULL" condition of materialized view not met

Tags: cassandra

I have this table and materialized view:

```
CREATE TABLE bubu (
    a text,
    b text,
    c text,
    d text,
    PRIMARY KEY (a, b));


CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW bubu_mv AS
    SELECT *
    FROM bubu
    WHERE a IS NOT NULL AND b IS NOT NULL AND c IS NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (a, c, b)
```

When I do this insert and then this update, the insert succeeds but the update returns **write timeout**:

```
insert into bubu (a,b,c,d) values ('1','2',null,'3');
update bubu set d = '5' where a = '1' and b = '2';
WriteTimeout: Error from server: code=1100 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 0 responses." info={'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'}
```

this happens on cassandra 3.7 and does not happen on cassandra 3.2.1 (just 2 versions I tried).

also, if the insert is like this, it does not happen:

```
insert into bubu (a,b) values ('1','2');
```

If I increase write_request_timeout_in_ms in conf/cassandra.yaml to 20000, I get timeout after ~10 seconds:

```
update bubu set d = '5' where a = '1' and b = '2';
OperationTimedOut: errors={}, last_host=127.0.0.1
```

Is this a bug in cassandra or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Can you increase timeout value in the config file `conf/cassandra.yaml` and check. Restart your server if it requires.

```
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 20000
```

Comment: Did it. Now I get OperationTimedOut after 10 seconds